# Jquery insertAfter 1 character after selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to load some text dynamically after an anchor tag but there's a period at the end of that hyperlink.

```
<a title="somelink" href="some url">This is the link</a>.
```

Trying to do this:

```
    $('<div class="addedText" />').insertAfter('a[title=\"somelink\"]');
    $('.addedText').load('extraText.txt');
```

Now it is doing this:

This is the link
extraText here
.  <-

That period at the end is what I want to avoid.

Comment: Why not delete the period? Also can you provide more of your html?

Comment: the text is coming in through a webservice.  I do not have control over it.  That's why I'm selecting the anchor with the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you'd have that period there in the first place, but you could solve it like this:

```
$($('a[title="somelink"]').get(0).nextSibling).after('<div class="addedText" />');
```

or

```
$('<div class="addedText" />').insertAfter($('a[title="somelink"]').get(0).nextSibling);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/t7Rhg/)

**EDIT:**

If there is a strong tag wrapping everything, it's a lot easier :

```
var strong = $('a[title="somelink"]').closest('strong');
$('<div class="addedText" />').insertAfter( strong );
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/t7Rhg/2/)

Comment: Thanks! there's a strong tag wrapping the sentence i forgot about how do I avoid that one?

Comment: There's a strong tag wrapping everything, the anchor and the period, and you'd like to insert the content after the strong tag ?

Comment: I hope you win Powerball because you deserve it.  Thanks a bunch!